# "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured" Error in my site

Tags: python, django, linux, websocket, django-channels

The error:

```
(venv) gamedeveloper@animechatapp:~$ sudo journalctl -u gunicorn -n 50
[sudo] password for gamedeveloper:
Sep 30 13:10:33 animechatapp gunicorn[510664]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not co>
Sep 30 13:10:33 animechatapp gunicorn[510664]: [2023-09-30 13:10:33 +0000] [510664] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 510664)
Sep 30 13:10:33 animechatapp systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 30 13:10:33 animechatapp systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 30 13:19:35 animechatapp systemd[1]: Started gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon.
Sep 30 13:19:35 animechatapp gunicorn[510824]: [2023-09-30 13:19:35 +0000] [510824] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
Sep 30 13:19:35 animechatapp gunicorn[510824]: [2023-09-30 13:19:35 +0000] [510824] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/run/gunicorn.sock (510824)
Sep 30 13:19:35 animechatapp gunicorn[510824]: [2023-09-30 13:19:35 +0000] [510824] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Sep 30 13:19:35 animechatapp gunicorn[510825]: [2023-09-30 13:19:35 +0000] [510825] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 510825
Sep 30 13:19:35 animechatapp gunicorn[510826]: [2023-09-30 13:19:35 +0000] [510826] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 510826
Sep 30 13:19:35 animechatapp gunicorn[510827]: [2023-09-30 13:19:35 +0000] [510827] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 510827
Sep 30 13:19:40 animechatapp gunicorn[510827]:  - - [30/Sep/2023:13:19:40 +0000] "POST /update_active_status/ HTTP/1.0" 200 21 "http://194.195.119.23>
Sep 30 13:19:43 animechatapp gunicorn[510826]:  - - [30/Sep/2023:13:19:43 +0000] "POST /update_active_status/ HTTP/1.0" 200 21 "http://194.195.119.23>
Sep 30 13:20:01 animechatapp gunicorn[510826]:  - - [30/Sep/2023:13:20:01 +0000] "POST /update_active_status/ HTTP/1.0" 200 21 "http://194.195.119.23>
Sep 30 13:20:02 animechatapp gunicorn[510827]:  - - [30/Sep/2023:13:20:02 +0000] "POST /update_active_status/ HTTP/1.0" 200 21 "http://194.195.119.23>
Sep 30 13:25:01 animechatapp gunicorn[510825]: [2023-09-30 13:25:01 +0000] [510825] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 510825)
Sep 30 13:25:01 animechatapp systemd[1]: Stopping gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon...
Sep 30 13:25:01 animechatapp gunicorn[510826]: [2023-09-30 13:25:01 +0000] [510826] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 510826)
Sep 30 13:25:01 animechatapp gunicorn[510824]: [2023-09-30 13:25:01 +0000] [510824] [INFO] Handling signal: term
Sep 30 13:25:01 animechatapp gunicorn[510827]: [2023-09-30 13:25:01 +0000] [510827] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 510827)
Sep 30 13:25:02 animechatapp gunicorn[510824]: [2023-09-30 13:25:02 +0000] [510824] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Sep 30 13:25:02 animechatapp systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 30 13:25:02 animechatapp systemd[1]: Stopped gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon.
Sep 30 13:25:02 animechatapp systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Consumed 1.658s CPU time.
Sep 30 13:25:02 animechatapp systemd[1]: Started gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon.
Sep 30 13:25:02 animechatapp gunicorn[510889]: [2023-09-30 13:25:02 +0000] [510889] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
Sep 30 13:25:02 animechatapp gunicorn[510889]: [2023-09-30 13:25:02 +0000] [510889] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/run/gunicorn.sock (510889)
Sep 30 13:25:02 animechatapp gunicorn[510889]: [2023-09-30 13:25:02 +0000] [510889] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Sep 30 13:25:02 animechatapp gunicorn[510892]: [2023-09-30 13:25:02 +0000] [510892] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 510892
Sep 30 13:25:02 animechatapp gunicorn[510893]: [2023-09-30 13:25:02 +0000] [510893] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 510893
Sep 30 13:25:02 animechatapp gunicorn[510894]: [2023-09-30 13:25:02 +0000] [510894] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 510894
Sep 30 13:27:09 animechatapp systemd[1]: Stopping gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon...
Sep 30 13:27:09 animechatapp gunicorn[510892]: [2023-09-30 13:27:09 +0000] [510892] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 510892)
Sep 30 13:27:09 animechatapp gunicorn[510893]: [2023-09-30 13:27:09 +0000] [510893] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 510893)
Sep 30 13:27:09 animechatapp gunicorn[510894]: [2023-09-30 13:27:09 +0000] [510894] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 510894)
Sep 30 13:27:09 animechatapp gunicorn[510889]: [2023-09-30 13:27:09 +0000] [510889] [INFO] Handling signal: term
Sep 30 13:27:09 animechatapp gunicorn[510889]: [2023-09-30 13:27:09 +0000] [510889] [ERROR] Worker (pid:510892) was sent SIGTERM!
Sep 30 13:27:09 animechatapp gunicorn[510889]: [2023-09-30 13:27:09 +0000] [510889] [ERROR] Worker (pid:510894) was sent SIGTERM!
Sep 30 13:27:09 animechatapp gunicorn[510889]: [2023-09-30 13:27:09 +0000] [510889] [ERROR] Worker (pid:510893) was sent SIGTERM!
Sep 30 13:27:09 animechatapp gunicorn[510889]: [2023-09-30 13:27:09 +0000] [510889] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Sep 30 13:27:09 animechatapp systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Deactivated successfully.
lines 1-41
```

The following is settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY ="secret_key"'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my.ip.address']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'daphne',
    'channels',
    'common_anime_chat.apps.CommonAnimeChatConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'anime.apps.AnimeConfig',
]



MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'anime_chat_app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'anime_chat_app.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
        'default':{
'database':'info'
                }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    }
]

LOGGING_CONFIG = None

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

import os

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
#CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'common-anime-chat-home'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'anime_chat_app.asgi.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
    },
}
```

I looked up some info online and one of the solutions was adding "LOGGING_CONFIG = None" in my settings.py file but that does not seem to solve this error. I was getting that error before adding this statement. I haven't added many log files in my server and I haven't added any statements in my code that references ANY log files.